# Explain 2 nginx errors that result in a 502 Bad Gateway response

Tags: ssl, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, hosting, ghost

I'm hosting a Ghost blog using Digital Ocean. My droplet is **Ubuntu Ghost 0.8.0 on 14.04**.

Yesterday I successfully installed a TLS/SSL certificate from [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) in order to enable HTTPS. The site was working fine then and this morning.

Today I uploaded a new Ghost theme and restarted Ghost in order to access it. I now get the response `502 Bad Gateway` when I try to access the site.

Each request for the site adds an instance of the following errors to my`nginx` error log.

Would someone walk me through what these 2 error messages mean? I'd really appreciate it.

*Please note that I've substituted my actual domain name with **example.com***

```
2016/06/16 17:28:45 [error] 8125#0: *13 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 98.247.253.8, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:2368/favicon.ico", host: “example.com”, referrer: "https://example.com/“
2016/06/16 17:30:14 [error] 8125#0: *18 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 98.247.253.8, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:2368/", host: “example.com”
```

Comment: What service is running on port 2368? It is probably down for some reason.

Comment: Maybe there's a firewall in front of the upstream server that's blocking incoming connections? Try a simple request from the machine that's running Nginx: `$ curl http://127.0.0.1:2368` and see.